# Imitate a DNS via UDP in Python

Tags: python, sockets, dns, udp

I want to imitate a DNS, like nslookup in python with UDP sockets. How should I build up the request?

```py
import socket

UDP_IP = '8.8.8.8'
UDP_PORT = 53

dn = 'www.google.com'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
msg = '???'

sock.sendto(msg, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

(data, addr) = sock.recvfrom(1024)

print data, addr
```

Comment: See https://routley.io/tech/2017/12/28/hand-writing-dns-messages.html

Comment: If you're doing this in python you should definitely look into scapy (https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): it's way easier than manipulating raw byte strings. Documentation isn't great, but once you grok it, it's very powerful and easy to construct and decode packets.